# First loop slower in performance test

Tags: java, testing, data-structures, benchmarking

I wanted to see first hand how certain data structures behave. I started with `ArrayList` and populated it with objects of a custom class. But when I was playing around with it I noticed that running test method X on top it is performing much slower or if I do the same job twice the second time is up to 6 times faster.

Here are some examples:

```
private void generateItems(int amount)
{
    System.out.println("Populating list with " + amount + " items...");
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        items.add(new Item("Type", "Subtype", random.nextInt(width), random.nextInt(height)));
    }
    System.out.println(timePassed(time) + " List size: " + items.size());
}

private void sortList(int x, int y)
{
    System.out.println("Sorting list...");
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.sort(items, new ItemComparator(x, y));
    System.out.println(timePassed(time) + " List sorted.");
    System.out.println("First: " + items.get(0));
}
```

Now let's run these two methods two times:

```
    items = new ArrayList<>();
    generateItems(100000); //33ms
    sortList(0, 0); //118ms

    items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    generateItems(100000); //5ms
    sortList(0, 0); //28ms
```

I understand when I sort an already sorted list would take less time because the computer gets better at gambling the outcome but here I generate two completely random lists.

I some more methods involving iteration and conditional item retrieval and they all behave the same: the first one is much slower then if it would run later.

In order to proceed with my tests on other data structures I want to know more about this behavior. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here or is the outcome expected and why? How do I make somewhat reliable tests like these?

Comment: Yep thats what I thought but could not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here or is the outcome expected and why?

Yes, Java is a JVM with a JIT by default.  This means the code is compiled dynamically as it is run.  So to start with it run slowly but speeds up as it gets better sampling data on how the program is run.

You can use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` on the command line to see some details. Note some methods will be compiled multiple times, sometimes with more expensive compilation optimization, sometimes because it has better data to optimize the code.

> How do I make somewhat reliable tests like these?

The simple answer is to run the test repeatedly and ignore the first 2 seconds of the benchmark at least.

For a better answer, use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).  By default, this will run each test for 10 seconds, 20 times over and ignores this warm up before running the actual tests and a host of better ways to write micro-benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks, I find this a better answer then the duplicate. The duplicate answer is talking about `warmup` is there any way of knowing when things are `cooling down`?

Comment: @MennoGouw Yes, when you restart the program, it cools down.  There is no notification that a method has been de-optimised or exactly why unfortunately however if you run the code the same way repeatedly, this shouldn't happen (but it does happen in real programs) The option I mention does say when a method has been de-optimised.

Answer (score 1):

```
How do I make somewhat reliable tests like these?
```

Don't use manual benchmark, use [OpenJdk/jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/):

```
class MyTest {
@Benchmark
private void generateItemsTest() {
   generateItems(100000);
}

 @Benchmark
private void sortListTest() {       
   generateItems(100000);
   sort(0, 0)
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(MyTest.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }
```

In pom.xml of maven you shoud add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmh-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or install JMH in your project another way